# Shopify use other apps on same domain

Tags: shopify

Currently I want to generate some dynamic pages in my shopify store bases on data I have in my Laravel application. Right now my shopify domain is on (example) https://example.com. I want to use my Laravel app on https://example.com/application. Is this somehow possible? Can I configure this in shopify? (I don't want to use a subdomain).

I can't find anything on the web regarding to this subject. Can't find any nginx or apache configuration in shopify.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't access any nginx or apache settings when using Shopify because they are running a SaaS model with all their backend code walled off. The only server side access you are given is through the liquid templating engine or via their APIs.

You have 2 options:

1. Use **example.com/application** to serve data via APIs to your Shopify store. You can fetch that data with JS inside liquid templates or inside Shopify pages. Of course you will be limited in using Shopify urls, that means something like this **example.com/pages/application**.
2. I know you don't want to use a subdomain, but it's actually a popular solution to run your main platform on **example.com**, and your Shopify platform on something like **shop.example.com**, this of course brings some other challenges, such as using their multipass to auth users across both platform (if this is something you want), but you do have the advantage of eventually being able to migrate the whole Shopify experience on your own platform (except perhaps the checkout flow). For example, you can use their graphQL APIs to get data about collections/products/carts then render those on your own platform and just use Shopify as a headless e-commerce backend.

Comment: Thanks Marius too bad shopify does not support this out of the box :(

Comment: You can also use a proxy (restricted to certain URLs) https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-dynamic-store-data-with-app-proxies